# Does the spring security filterchain always run twice for Asynchronous requests?

Tags: spring, asynchronous, spring-security

From what I can tell, the spring security filterchain runs twice per request for @Async requests, because it runs on the inbound request thread, is passed to the async code which runs on a different thread, and then when it attempts to write to the response thread the security filterchain runs again.  I believe this is due to the use of a ThreadLocal for storing the security context.

I am able to successfully pass the security context into the asynchronous code, the issue is whenever I attempt to write the response the filterchain runs again.

I am encountering a similar situation as described here:

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/747178-security-filter-chain-is-always-calling-authenticationmanager-twice-per-request

Is this simply expected behavior that we should account for when using spring security, or is there a configuration I am missing that would prevent the second execution of the filterchain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got an answer here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/736

apparently the fix is to `configure security.filter-dispatcher-types=REQUEST, ERROR`

Answer (score 0):

Set property `spring.security.filter.dispatcher-types=REQUEST,ERROR`. Spring will not apply filters for call dispatched from async context.